# how to split line in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, cmd

I have a file that contain few lines, each line contain is an url-

```
http://some_address1/some_page1/anther_page1/my_target1
http://some_address2/some_page2/some_page2/my_target2
...
```

And I want to create new file, that will have the end of each url-

```
my-target1
my_target2
...
```

How do I do this in Linux cmd?

Comment: Please show your attempts. Hint: It can be done easily in `awk` or `sed`

Comment: The url's doesn't in the same length and doesn't end in the same pattern, so I need to cat every url by fined the last "/" in each url.

Comment: @yiaca : `man basename`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use awk, set `/` as field delimiter and `print` the last field (`$NF`):

```
$ awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file
```

Output:

```
my_target1
my_target2
...
```

*to create new file, that will have the end of each url* add `> newfile` after the above command. That will create a new file named `newfile` or overwrite it if it pre-existed and send the above output to it.

Comment: As I understand the question, @yiaca wants to create (empty ?) files, not just printing the end of the URL. awk -F/ '/^http/{ print $0 > $NF}' would be more fitting (it writes the entire line in the file whose name is the last field).

Comment: We'll just have to wait for op to return and elaborate on that.

Comment: "...or overwrite pre-existing file by the same name and send the above output to it." Are you saying update the file with `awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file > file`? The OS would truncate before the read...

Comment: @PaulHodges No, I'm saying `awk ... file > newfile` would overwrite possibly pre-existing `newfile`. Not sure if my fix made it any clearer, thou. :D Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `basename`:

```sh
basename "http://some_address1/some_page1/anther_page1/my_target1"
```

Apply for all lines in a file:

```sh
xargs basename < urls_file
```

Comment: Interesting use of `basename`

Comment: `xargs basename < in > out` eliminates the UUoC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bash command where `file` is the path of the input file, and `output` the path of the desired output:

```
while read line; do basename $line; done < file > output
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash array and Parameter Expansion, requires bash4+ because of `mapfile`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t urls < file.txt

for i in "${urls[@]##*/}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

- Replace `printf '%s\n' "$i"` with `touch "$i"` or just `> "$i"` to create a new empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's|^.*/||' file > new_file
```

Comment: I thought it did. It's exactly the solution I'd've given.